# Transform Scale and adjust outside content

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I got a `div` and I need it to scale between `0` and `1`, but the later content stays in the same place. How do I increase the div, and modify the content around it?
[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/eusm92vh/)

```css
.transform {
  background-color: slategray;
}

.transform:hover~.div1 {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.div1 {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  background-color: royalblue;
  padding: 15px;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transition: transform 2s;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: springgreen;
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="transform">TRANSFORM</div>
<div class="div1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <span>TEXT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: What div are you trying to change, what are you trying to transform and what is not working as it should? Please give more detail to your question.

Comment: DIV2 should move when DIV1 scale between 0 and 1

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1450qfjh/1/

Comment: @JoykalInfotech There is no transition between `display:inline-block` and `display:none`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the height of .div1 instead of scaling it, the rest of the page will adjust to it.

```css
.transform {
  background-color: slategray;
}

.transform:hover~.div1 {
  height:0; padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0; /* need to adjust height and padding */
}

.div1 {
  background-color: royalblue;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: padding-top 2s, padding-bottom 2s, height 2s; /* animate the padding too */
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: springgreen;
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  width:200px; height: 100%; vertical-align:top; /* and some adjustments here */
}
```

```html
<div class="transform">TRANSFORM</div>
<div class="div1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <span>TEXT</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

---

Edit: comments by the OP have changed the problem now, so here is a new snippet addressing that.

```css
.transform {
  background-color: slategray;
}

.transform:hover~.div1 {
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.transform:hover~.div2 {
  top:-230px;             /* Move div2 up by the height+padding of div1 */
}

.div1 {
  transform: scaleY(1);
  background-color: royalblue;
  padding: 15px;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transition: transform 2s;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: springgreen;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;  /* use relative positioning */
  top: 0;              /* Initial position is where it normally is */
  transition: top 2s;
}

img {
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 300px">TEXT</div>
<div class="transform">TRANSFORM</div>
<div class="div1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <span>TEXT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem of using height are if I have content above, the animation goes up and not down, thats why I switched to transform scale. See an example using your code https://jsfiddle.net/ktLub56j/

Comment: @gSalzmann OK, I added another solution based on our new info. How does the bottom snippet look?

Comment: Animate the other DIV, yeah, sounds interesting. I will implement with my project

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use `max-height` to transform your div instead of the `transform` property.

```css
.transform {
  background-color: slategray;

}

.transform:hover~.div1 {
  max-height: 0;
}

.transform:hover~.div1 img {
  max-height: 0;
}

.div1 {
  max-height: 600px;
  background-color: royalblue;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: springgreen;
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
 max-height: 200px;
 transition: max-height 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="transform">TRANSFORM</div>
<div class="div1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <span>TEXT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the blue part still showing up, would be a problem for OP.

Comment: Yes, that's from the padding. It could be removed also.

Comment: The problem of using height are if I have content above, the animation goes up and not down, thats why I switched to transform scale. See an example https://jsfiddle.net/35xj4kzw

Comment: Okay, I see. But wouldn't this happen no matter what if you manage to get rid of the space (i.e. keep div2 next to div1)?

Comment: @JacobLockard i think it's just because they don't have any space underneath, if it's the last thing on the page - so it's bound to go down. If there is additional content below, it will go up. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/90dvfokj/

Comment: Yeah. What I meant was: Even if you could get transform to not keep the extra space between the `div`s you would still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could change `transform: scaleY(0);` to `height:0px;`. It should give you the same effect but move the below div too. I've created an example that may help you below.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.transform {
  background-color: slategray;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: royalblue;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: all 2s;
  height: 200px;
}

.transform:hover~.div1 {
  height: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: springgreen;
  font-size: 20px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 150px">

</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="transform">TRANSFORM</div>
  <div class="div1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <span>TEXT</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 200px">

</div>
```

Comment: The problem of using height are if I have content above, the animation goes up and not down, thats why I switched to transform scale. See an example https://jsfiddle.net/35xj4kzw

Comment: @gSalzmann If you have space underneath too, then it will still move up - it is just because it's at the bottom. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/90dvfokj/